# How to modify nav-pills to limit the number of pages to display

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a pagination system using `nav-pills`. Since these `nav-pills` are created dynamically, there will be times when there are only 1, and others when there are 100 (or more).

I am using `bootstrap 4` & `Django`

The visual impact is tremendous when there are a large number of `nav-pills`.

Attached photo to give you an idea:

[image: Example when large number of pills]

The code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
  {% for evidence_form in evidence_formset %}
  {% with index=forloop.counter|stringformat:'s' %}
  {% with id='evidence-form-'|add:index|add:'-tab' href='#evidence-form-'|add:index aria_controls='evidence-form-'|add:index %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    {% if not current_tab and forloop.first or current_tab == index %}
    <a class="nav-link active" id="{{ id }}" data-toggle="pill" href="{{ href }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="true">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
    {% else %}
    <a class="nav-link" id="{{ id }}" data-toggle="pill" href="{{ href }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="false">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I would like to get a result similar to the following:

`Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next`

That is, if the user clicks next, the following 5 pills will load:

`Previous 6 7 8 9 10 Next`

And if the user clicks on `Previous` we will go back to the previous 5 pills:

`Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next`

What would be the best way to achieve this result? Is there a predefined solution for bootstrap?

`UPDATE with what I've tried (2021/07/07):`

`views.py`

```
paginator = Paginator(SomeFormSet, 1)
try:
    forms = paginator.page(1)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    forms = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    forms = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context['forms'] = forms
```

`index.html`:

```
  {% for form in forms %}
  {% if forms.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
      {% if forms.has_previous %}
        <li><a class="nav-link active" id="evidence-form-{{ forms.previous_page_number }}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-{{ forms.previous_page_number }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="true">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for i in forms.paginator.page_range %}
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        {% if forms.number == i %}
          <a class="nav-link active" id="evidence-form-{{ i }}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-{{ i }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="true">{{ i }}</a>
        {% elif i > forms.number|add:'-5' and i < forms.number|add:'5' %}
          <a class="nav-link" id="evidence-form-{{ i }}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-{{ i }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="false">{{ i }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if forms.has_next %}
        <li><a class="nav-link" id="evidence-form-{{ forms.next_page_number }}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-{{ forms.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Update 2021/07/08:

Each page correspond to a tab-pane with an id following this pattern: `evidence-form-` as you can see in my prev code. That is why I can't use `?page={{ page }}` at all (or yes, but somehow I have to link `?page={{ page }}` with a specific `formset` and I don't know how).

[image]

Comment: You might want to just do this in Javascript. It looks like the links are all the same and just indexed so you could have a relatively simple javascript function and some event listeners for Previous / Next to increment. Does that make sense / sound doable?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense! Is there a similar implementation to get inspired? I already imagined that something like this would be necessary but I was also hoping that bootstrap would have some class predefined for these situations.

Comment: Yeah not sure on bootstrap.. here's a decent example of something similar: https://www.codingnepalweb.com/pagination-ui-design-javascript/

Comment: I will check it out, thanks. I also found some plugins but I'd like to avoid installing plugins and do it in the most minimalist way possible: https://github.com/josecebe/twbs-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

javascript part:

```
function nextPages(){

  var maxPages = "{{evidence_formset|length}}";
  const container = document.querySelector("#evidence-formset-tab");
  const matches = container.querySelectorAll("li > a");
  var nextPagesArray = [];
  var htmlstring = "";
  var nextButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='nextPages()'>Next</button>";
  var prevButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='prevPages()'>Previous</button>";
  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    nextPagesArray.push(parseInt(matches[i].textContent)+5);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < nextPagesArray.length; i++) {
    if (nextPagesArray[i] <= maxPages) {
      htmlstring += "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' id='evidence-form-'"+nextPagesArray[i]+" data-toggle='pill' href='#evidence-form-"+nextPagesArray[i]+"' role='tab' aria-controls='evidence-form-"+nextPagesArray[i]+"' aria-selected='false'>"+nextPagesArray[i]+" </a></li>";
    }
  }



  if (htmlstring != "") {
    htmlstring = prevButton + htmlstring + nextButton;
    document.getElementById("evidence-formset-tab").innerHTML = htmlstring;
  }


}

function prevPages(){

var minPage = 1;
var maxPages = parseInt("{{evidence_formset|length}}");
const container = document.querySelector("#evidence-formset-tab");
const matches = container.querySelectorAll("li > a");
var prevPagesArray = [];
var pageSubSets = [];
var htmlstring = "";
var nextButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='nextPages()'>Next</button>";
var prevButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='prevPages()'>Previous</button>";
var arrayPages = [];

for (var i = minPage; i <= maxPages; i++) {
  arrayPages.push(i);
}

var i,j, chunk = 5;
for (i = 0,j = arrayPages.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    pageSubSets.push(arrayPages.slice(i, i + chunk));
}


for (var k = 0; k < matches.length; k++) {
  if(pageSubSets[pageSubSets.length-1].includes(parseInt(matches[k].textContent))){
    prevPagesArray = pageSubSets[pageSubSets.length-2];
    break;
  }
  else {
    prevPagesArray.push(parseInt(matches[k].textContent)-5);
  }
}
```

html part:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="prevPages()">Previous</button>
    {% for evidence_form in evidence_formset %}
    {% with index=forloop.counter|stringformat:'s' %}
    {% with id='evidence-form-'|add:index|add:'-tab' href='#evidence-form-'|add:index aria_controls='evidence-form-'|add:index %}
    {% if forloop.counter < 6 %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      {% if not current_tab and forloop.first or current_tab == index %}
      <a class="nav-link active" id="{{ id }}" data-toggle="pill" href="{{ href }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="true">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="nav-link" id="{{ id }}" data-toggle="pill" href="{{ href }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ aria_controls }}" aria-selected="false">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="nextPages()">Next</button>
  </ul>
```

In the end the solution was purely with javascript, it was not necessary to use django's pagination module.

I'm sure it can be optimized, but for now it works and that's what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 08.07.2021 - reformatted and redefined answer:

Since my original answer did not match your question here some other code:

Django View:

```py
def testing_view(request):
    # 500 Items in Array (Your FormSet)
    objects = [('foobar_0', 0), ('foobar_1', 1), ('foobar_2', 2), ('foobar_3', 3), ('foobar_4', 4), ('foobar_5', 5),
               ('foobar_6', 6), ('foobar_7', 7), ('foobar_8', 8), ('foobar_9', 9), ('foobar_10', 10), ('foobar_11', 11),
               ('foobar_12', 12), ('foobar_13', 13), ('foobar_14', 14), ('foobar_15', 15), ('foobar_16', 16),
               ('foobar_17', 17), ('foobar_18', 18), ('foobar_19', 19), ('foobar_20', 20), ('foobar_21', 21),
               ('foobar_22', 22), ('foobar_23', 23), ('foobar_24', 24), ('foobar_25', 25), ('foobar_26', 26),
               ('foobar_27', 27), ('foobar_28', 28), ('foobar_29', 29), ('foobar_30', 30), ('foobar_31', 31),
               ('foobar_32', 32), ('foobar_33', 33), ('foobar_34', 34), ('foobar_35', 35), ('foobar_36', 36),
               ('foobar_37', 37), ('foobar_38', 38), ('foobar_39', 39), ('foobar_40', 40), ('foobar_41', 41),
               ('foobar_42', 42), ('foobar_43', 43), ('foobar_44', 44), ('foobar_45', 45), ('foobar_46', 46),
               ('foobar_47', 47), ('foobar_48', 48), ('foobar_49', 49), ('foobar_50', 50), ('foobar_51', 51),
               ('foobar_52', 52), ('foobar_53', 53), ('foobar_54', 54), ('foobar_55', 55), ('foobar_56', 56),
               ('foobar_57', 57), ('foobar_58', 58), ('foobar_59', 59), ('foobar_60', 60), ('foobar_61', 61),
               ('foobar_62', 62), ('foobar_63', 63), ('foobar_64', 64), ('foobar_65', 65), ('foobar_66', 66),
               ('foobar_67', 67), ('foobar_68', 68), ('foobar_69', 69), ('foobar_70', 70), ('foobar_71', 71),
               ('foobar_72', 72), ('foobar_73', 73), ('foobar_74', 74), ('foobar_75', 75), ('foobar_76', 76),
               ('foobar_77', 77), ('foobar_78', 78), ('foobar_79', 79), ('foobar_80', 80), ('foobar_81', 81),
               ('foobar_82', 82), ('foobar_83', 83), ('foobar_84', 84), ('foobar_85', 85), ('foobar_86', 86),
               ('foobar_87', 87), ('foobar_88', 88), ('foobar_89', 89), ('foobar_90', 90), ('foobar_91', 91),
               ('foobar_92', 92), ('foobar_93', 93), ('foobar_94', 94), ('foobar_95', 95), ('foobar_96', 96),
               ('foobar_97', 97), ('foobar_98', 98), ('foobar_99', 99), ('foobar_100', 100), ('foobar_101', 101),
               ('foobar_102', 102), ('foobar_103', 103), ('foobar_104', 104), ('foobar_105', 105), ('foobar_106', 106),
               ('foobar_107', 107), ('foobar_108', 108), ('foobar_109', 109), ('foobar_110', 110), ('foobar_111', 111),
               ('foobar_112', 112), ('foobar_113', 113), ('foobar_114', 114), ('foobar_115', 115), ('foobar_116', 116),
               ('foobar_117', 117), ('foobar_118', 118), ('foobar_119', 119), ('foobar_120', 120), ('foobar_121', 121),
               ('foobar_122', 122), ('foobar_123', 123), ('foobar_124', 124), ('foobar_125', 125), ('foobar_126', 126),
               ('foobar_127', 127), ('foobar_128', 128), ('foobar_129', 129), ('foobar_130', 130), ('foobar_131', 131),
               ('foobar_132', 132), ('foobar_133', 133), ('foobar_134', 134), ('foobar_135', 135), ('foobar_136', 136),
               ('foobar_137', 137), ('foobar_138', 138), ('foobar_139', 139), ('foobar_140', 140), ('foobar_141', 141),
               ('foobar_142', 142), ('foobar_143', 143), ('foobar_144', 144), ('foobar_145', 145), ('foobar_146', 146),
               ('foobar_147', 147), ('foobar_148', 148), ('foobar_149', 149), ('foobar_150', 150), ('foobar_151', 151),
               ('foobar_152', 152), ('foobar_153', 153), ('foobar_154', 154), ('foobar_155', 155), ('foobar_156', 156),
               ('foobar_157', 157), ('foobar_158', 158), ('foobar_159', 159), ('foobar_160', 160), ('foobar_161', 161),
               ('foobar_162', 162), ('foobar_163', 163), ('foobar_164', 164), ('foobar_165', 165), ('foobar_166', 166),
               ('foobar_167', 167), ('foobar_168', 168), ('foobar_169', 169), ('foobar_170', 170), ('foobar_171', 171),
               ('foobar_172', 172), ('foobar_173', 173), ('foobar_174', 174), ('foobar_175', 175), ('foobar_176', 176),
               ('foobar_177', 177), ('foobar_178', 178), ('foobar_179', 179), ('foobar_180', 180), ('foobar_181', 181),
               ('foobar_182', 182), ('foobar_183', 183), ('foobar_184', 184), ('foobar_185', 185), ('foobar_186', 186),
               ('foobar_187', 187), ('foobar_188', 188), ('foobar_189', 189), ('foobar_190', 190), ('foobar_191', 191),
               ('foobar_192', 192), ('foobar_193', 193), ('foobar_194', 194), ('foobar_195', 195), ('foobar_196', 196),
               ('foobar_197', 197), ('foobar_198', 198), ('foobar_199', 199), ('foobar_200', 200), ('foobar_201', 201),
               ('foobar_202', 202), ('foobar_203', 203), ('foobar_204', 204), ('foobar_205', 205), ('foobar_206', 206),
               ('foobar_207', 207), ('foobar_208', 208), ('foobar_209', 209), ('foobar_210', 210), ('foobar_211', 211),
               ('foobar_212', 212), ('foobar_213', 213), ('foobar_214', 214), ('foobar_215', 215), ('foobar_216', 216),
               ('foobar_217', 217), ('foobar_218', 218), ('foobar_219', 219), ('foobar_220', 220), ('foobar_221', 221),
               ('foobar_222', 222), ('foobar_223', 223), ('foobar_224', 224), ('foobar_225', 225), ('foobar_226', 226),
               ('foobar_227', 227), ('foobar_228', 228), ('foobar_229', 229), ('foobar_230', 230), ('foobar_231', 231),
               ('foobar_232', 232), ('foobar_233', 233), ('foobar_234', 234), ('foobar_235', 235), ('foobar_236', 236),
               ('foobar_237', 237), ('foobar_238', 238), ('foobar_239', 239), ('foobar_240', 240), ('foobar_241', 241),
               ('foobar_242', 242), ('foobar_243', 243), ('foobar_244', 244), ('foobar_245', 245), ('foobar_246', 246),
               ('foobar_247', 247), ('foobar_248', 248), ('foobar_249', 249), ('foobar_250', 250), ('foobar_251', 251),
               ('foobar_252', 252), ('foobar_253', 253), ('foobar_254', 254), ('foobar_255', 255), ('foobar_256', 256),
               ('foobar_257', 257), ('foobar_258', 258), ('foobar_259', 259), ('foobar_260', 260), ('foobar_261', 261),
               ('foobar_262', 262), ('foobar_263', 263), ('foobar_264', 264), ('foobar_265', 265), ('foobar_266', 266),
               ('foobar_267', 267), ('foobar_268', 268), ('foobar_269', 269), ('foobar_270', 270), ('foobar_271', 271),
               ('foobar_272', 272), ('foobar_273', 273), ('foobar_274', 274), ('foobar_275', 275), ('foobar_276', 276),
               ('foobar_277', 277), ('foobar_278', 278), ('foobar_279', 279), ('foobar_280', 280), ('foobar_281', 281),
               ('foobar_282', 282), ('foobar_283', 283), ('foobar_284', 284), ('foobar_285', 285), ('foobar_286', 286),
               ('foobar_287', 287), ('foobar_288', 288), ('foobar_289', 289), ('foobar_290', 290), ('foobar_291', 291),
               ('foobar_292', 292), ('foobar_293', 293), ('foobar_294', 294), ('foobar_295', 295), ('foobar_296', 296),
               ('foobar_297', 297), ('foobar_298', 298), ('foobar_299', 299), ('foobar_300', 300), ('foobar_301', 301),
               ('foobar_302', 302), ('foobar_303', 303), ('foobar_304', 304), ('foobar_305', 305), ('foobar_306', 306),
               ('foobar_307', 307), ('foobar_308', 308), ('foobar_309', 309), ('foobar_310', 310), ('foobar_311', 311),
               ('foobar_312', 312), ('foobar_313', 313), ('foobar_314', 314), ('foobar_315', 315), ('foobar_316', 316),
               ('foobar_317', 317), ('foobar_318', 318), ('foobar_319', 319), ('foobar_320', 320), ('foobar_321', 321),
               ('foobar_322', 322), ('foobar_323', 323), ('foobar_324', 324), ('foobar_325', 325), ('foobar_326', 326),
               ('foobar_327', 327), ('foobar_328', 328), ('foobar_329', 329), ('foobar_330', 330), ('foobar_331', 331),
               ('foobar_332', 332), ('foobar_333', 333), ('foobar_334', 334), ('foobar_335', 335), ('foobar_336', 336),
               ('foobar_337', 337), ('foobar_338', 338), ('foobar_339', 339), ('foobar_340', 340), ('foobar_341', 341),
               ('foobar_342', 342), ('foobar_343', 343), ('foobar_344', 344), ('foobar_345', 345), ('foobar_346', 346),
               ('foobar_347', 347), ('foobar_348', 348), ('foobar_349', 349), ('foobar_350', 350), ('foobar_351', 351),
               ('foobar_352', 352), ('foobar_353', 353), ('foobar_354', 354), ('foobar_355', 355), ('foobar_356', 356),
               ('foobar_357', 357), ('foobar_358', 358), ('foobar_359', 359), ('foobar_360', 360), ('foobar_361', 361),
               ('foobar_362', 362), ('foobar_363', 363), ('foobar_364', 364), ('foobar_365', 365), ('foobar_366', 366),
               ('foobar_367', 367), ('foobar_368', 368), ('foobar_369', 369), ('foobar_370', 370), ('foobar_371', 371),
               ('foobar_372', 372), ('foobar_373', 373), ('foobar_374', 374), ('foobar_375', 375), ('foobar_376', 376),
               ('foobar_377', 377), ('foobar_378', 378), ('foobar_379', 379), ('foobar_380', 380), ('foobar_381', 381),
               ('foobar_382', 382), ('foobar_383', 383), ('foobar_384', 384), ('foobar_385', 385), ('foobar_386', 386),
               ('foobar_387', 387), ('foobar_388', 388), ('foobar_389', 389), ('foobar_390', 390), ('foobar_391', 391),
               ('foobar_392', 392), ('foobar_393', 393), ('foobar_394', 394), ('foobar_395', 395), ('foobar_396', 396),
               ('foobar_397', 397), ('foobar_398', 398), ('foobar_399', 399), ('foobar_400', 400), ('foobar_401', 401),
               ('foobar_402', 402), ('foobar_403', 403), ('foobar_404', 404), ('foobar_405', 405), ('foobar_406', 406),
               ('foobar_407', 407), ('foobar_408', 408), ('foobar_409', 409), ('foobar_410', 410), ('foobar_411', 411),
               ('foobar_412', 412), ('foobar_413', 413), ('foobar_414', 414), ('foobar_415', 415), ('foobar_416', 416),
               ('foobar_417', 417), ('foobar_418', 418), ('foobar_419', 419), ('foobar_420', 420), ('foobar_421', 421),
               ('foobar_422', 422), ('foobar_423', 423), ('foobar_424', 424), ('foobar_425', 425), ('foobar_426', 426),
               ('foobar_427', 427), ('foobar_428', 428), ('foobar_429', 429), ('foobar_430', 430), ('foobar_431', 431),
               ('foobar_432', 432), ('foobar_433', 433), ('foobar_434', 434), ('foobar_435', 435), ('foobar_436', 436),
               ('foobar_437', 437), ('foobar_438', 438), ('foobar_439', 439), ('foobar_440', 440), ('foobar_441', 441),
               ('foobar_442', 442), ('foobar_443', 443), ('foobar_444', 444), ('foobar_445', 445), ('foobar_446', 446),
               ('foobar_447', 447), ('foobar_448', 448), ('foobar_449', 449), ('foobar_450', 450), ('foobar_451', 451),
               ('foobar_452', 452), ('foobar_453', 453), ('foobar_454', 454), ('foobar_455', 455), ('foobar_456', 456),
               ('foobar_457', 457), ('foobar_458', 458), ('foobar_459', 459), ('foobar_460', 460), ('foobar_461', 461),
               ('foobar_462', 462), ('foobar_463', 463), ('foobar_464', 464), ('foobar_465', 465), ('foobar_466', 466),
               ('foobar_467', 467), ('foobar_468', 468), ('foobar_469', 469), ('foobar_470', 470), ('foobar_471', 471),
               ('foobar_472', 472), ('foobar_473', 473), ('foobar_474', 474), ('foobar_475', 475), ('foobar_476', 476),
               ('foobar_477', 477), ('foobar_478', 478), ('foobar_479', 479), ('foobar_480', 480), ('foobar_481', 481),
               ('foobar_482', 482), ('foobar_483', 483), ('foobar_484', 484), ('foobar_485', 485), ('foobar_486', 486),
               ('foobar_487', 487), ('foobar_488', 488), ('foobar_489', 489), ('foobar_490', 490), ('foobar_491', 491),
               ('foobar_492', 492), ('foobar_493', 493), ('foobar_494', 494), ('foobar_495', 495), ('foobar_496', 496),
               ('foobar_497', 497), ('foobar_498', 498), ('foobar_499', 499)]
    return render(request, "testing.html", context={"total_elements": len(objects), "qs": objects})
```

All the pagination of your tab panel is done within js/html

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="tab-content" id=evidence-formset-tabContent">
                    {% for q in qs %}
                        <div class="tab-pane {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" id="tab-{{ q.1 }}"
                             role="tabpanel">{{ q.0 }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here we just generate an empty nav list with an id and all your pannel divs with your formset content to display.

```js
function generate_page_array(page_number, nav_pills_range) {
            let start = 0
            if ((page_number % nav_pills_range) == 0) {
                start = Math.floor((page_number - 1) / nav_pills_range) * nav_pills_range
            } else {
                start = Math.floor(page_number / nav_pills_range) * nav_pills_range
            }
            let end = nav_pills_range + start + 1
            let temp = []
            for (let i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
                temp.push(i)
            }
            return temp
        }

        function generate_pagination(page) {
            const max_entries = {{ total_elements|safe }};
            const menu = document.querySelector("#evidence-formset-tab")
            menu.innerHTML = ''
            const tmp_array = generate_page_array(page, 5);
            const prev = page > 5
            const next = page <= max_entries - 5
            if (prev) {
                menu.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                 <li class="nav-item">
                        <a onclick="generate_pagination(${page - 5})" class="nav-link">Prev</a>
                    </li>`)
            }
            tmp_array.forEach((e)=>{
                menu.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                 <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#tab-${e}" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">${e}</a>
                    </li>`)
            })

            if (next) {
                menu.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                 <li class="nav-item">
                        <a onclick="generate_pagination(${page + 5})" class="nav-link">Next</a>
                    </li>`)
            }
            console.log(prev, tmp_array, next)

        }

        window.onload = function () {
            generate_pagination(1);
        }
```

The javascript which generates your nav-pills according do your description.

Initial Call:

[image]

Looks like this if you click on any number
[image]

After clicking next:

[image]

After clicking any nav pill in the future:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain more how to adapt it to the provided code with pills? I tried but somehow I couldn't.

Comment: Changed my answer since I miss understood your initial question. This would be a way to implement it for the backend and the frontend only renders the page numbers returned.

Comment: Just updated my question with what I've tried so far so you can see the backend now. I tried pagination module, but somehow when I click >> (the equivalent of Next in my original question), the following 5 pages are not loading. Could you please help me? I will mark your answer as valid for sure.

Comment: I will have a look at it and update my answer. Let's see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: Added a working example with bootstrap and Django's Pagination. The rest is up to you :) Even you might mark my answer as valid, I will not implement the whole code for you. This is just a prove of concept how you could implement it. You will have to refine it. Hope it helps, best regards

Comment: Question updated, sorry for the misunderstanding. And sure, I don't need the full implementation, even pseudocode it's fine for me. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: I just totally miss understood your question....I hope now it is right. This should be done within the frontend and not within the django backend. I changed my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Although this does not answer my question, you were very close. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll need to use a lot of Javascript to configure this.

Why don't you send a URL GET Parameter for the current page and then calculate the number of pages you need to send next.

You can probably do something like this:

```
paginator = Paginator(SomeFormSet, 1)

try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
except:
    page = 1

try:
    forms = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    forms = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    forms = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

current_page = forms.number - 1

max_pages = len(paginator.page_range)

number_of_pages_to_display = 5

start_page_new = current_page - number_of_pages_to_display if current_page >= number_of_pages_to_display else 0
end_page_new = current_page + number_of_pages_to_display if current_page <= max_pages - number_of_pages_to_display else max_pages

page_range = list(paginator.page_range)[start_page_new:end_page_new]

context['forms'] = forms

return render(request, 'example.html', {
        'forms': forms,
        'page_range': page_range,
    })
```

Or for a shorted solution, you can also the current forloop.counter with a certain range:

```
{% page_obj.has_previous %}
<a class="page-link" href="?page=1" aria-label="Previous">
{% endif %}

{% for n in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
{% if page_obj.number == n %}

ACTIVE TAB HERE

{% elif n > page_obj.number|add:'-5' and n < page_obj.number|add:'5' %}

ONLY 5 ITEMS DISPLAYED

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
page next link
{% endif %}
```

[image: pagination]

Comment: As I did not understand first this is bootstrap tab view not real pagination, he just wanted to view the tabs as pagination’s. Nothing todo with backend pagination: my first solution looked like yours but didn’t match his question